# java swing displays incorrectly - squares covering content

Tags: java, swing, jframe

My problem is difficult to describe in words, but I have no reputation to post image :(. I have strange squares on my JOptionPanel, they are moving while I'm typing. What is more curious for me the same code works fine on other computers.

It is the code:

```
String inputValue = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please write, what does " + 
      res.get(0).getZ1() + " means ?");
```

It is the only one place where I need swing, so I think all code is useless, and it is something wrong with my computer, but dont know what.

[image]

I have Win8.1 and I use Eclipse, if you need any other informations please ask.

My video card is: Intel R HD Graphics 4000

Comment: email bit removed as that is not allowed. Please post a link to your images, and those of us with rep will be happy to post it into your question.

Comment: At least post the code that is giving you trouble.  You can load an image on an image sharing site and link to it.

Comment: What type of video card does your computer use? NVidia?

Comment: This is print screen http://imgur.com/IkJPqwv

Comment: Please see link to duplicate question. We've seen this before not infrequently.

Comment: Check out: [Java Hardware Acceleration not working with Intel Integrated Graphics](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14635377/java-hardware-acceleration-not-working-with-intel-integrated-graphics)